# Get Date From FileName and keep as variable DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

I need to keep the date in the filename as a DateTime variable
File always like

```
T201901150001.CDR
```

YYYY - MM - DD - minute - hour
How can it be done using DateTime.ParseExact() in .NET CORE
Thank You for answering! I tried something like this.lastRecord.Filename is string.\

```
DateTime parsedFile = DateTime.ParseExact(lastRecord.Filename.Substring(2,13),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: The index range within a string is `[0 .. Length - 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
string filename = "T201901150001.CDR";
string pattern = filename.Substring(1, 12);

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(pattern, "yyyyMMddmmHH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(date);
```

The substring removes the first letter and the extension.

Then we parse the string date part.

It can be adapted according to the `T[date-schema].EXT` pattern if it is different, therefore first index and char count will be changed, as well as the parameter `format` of the method `ParseExact`.

Also if the file name is a full path we can use:

```
string pattern = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename).Substring(1, 12);
```

*Output*

```
15/01/2019 01:00:00
```

*Improvement*

We can define a variable (useful if user can change this setting) or a const for the format and use its length instead of a literal, which will be better:

```
using System.IO;

const string FileDatePatternPrefix = "T";

const string FileDatePattern = "yyyyMMddmmHH";

string pattern = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)
                     .Substring(FileDatePatternPrefix.Length, FileDatePattern.Length);
```

Also format mismatching and exceptions may be handled...